# Delete children objects where create data is less than "X" hour - eZ Publish 5

Tags: php, cron, ezpublish

I need simple  php code for deleting children objects in ez publish 5, i'm  trying to  create  cron job  file and delete objects  in ez publish where created date is leess then "x"  hour , in my case it is  24 hour.
if  some have  had wrote    this code before, please  share it me too, it would be very helpful for me.

Best regards :)

```html
i trying  this  but not working and crack database:


#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

include_once( 'ezpublish_legacy/kernel/classes/ezcontentobjecttreenode.php' );
include_once( 'ezpublish_legacy/kernel/classes/ezcontentobject.php' );
include_once( 'ezpublish_legacy/kernel/classes/datatypes/ezuser/ezuser.php' );
include_once( 'ezpublish_legacy/lib/ezutils/classes/ezcli.php' );
include_once( 'ezpublish_legacy/kernel/classes/ezscript.php' );

$cli =& eZCLI::instance();
$script =& eZScript::instance();

$script->startup();

$script->initialize();

/**
 * @param array $classID
 * @param int $parentNodeID
 * @param int $depth
 * @param string $login
 * @param string $password
 */
function &deleteNodes ( $classID, $parentNodeID, $depth, $login, $password )
{
    eZUser::loginUser( $login, $password );

    $deleteIDArray = array();

    $nodeArray =& eZContentObjectTreeNode::subTree(  array(
        'ClassFilterType' => 'include',
        'ClassFilterArray' => $classID,
        'Depth' => $depth,
    ), $parentNodeID
    );
    foreach ( $nodeArray as $node )
    {
        $deleteIDArray[] = $node->attribute( 'main_node_id' );
    }

    eZContentObjectTreeNode::removeSubtrees( $deleteIDArray, false );
}

deleteNodes ( array( 230 ), 336, 1, 'admin', 'publish' );

$script->shutdown();
?>
```

Comment: let me share some info with you, we don't code for free, you have a problem with your code we help you, we don't code, better hire a developer

Comment: i need sample of code , i think it is not  a hard for users here and i think it is help!

Comment: if you think that i  need  write full code for me then you are  on the wrong way, i need example or links for tutorial where is explaining how it must done.

Comment: We like to see what you've tried to code first in an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: I edited my question and add sample of code what i'm trying to do but it's not working

Comment: Asking for a sample or links to a tutorial is off-topic for this site. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

This question is closed, i do not get  here clear answer and did it with to myself. i get only -1 for this question lol